# TypeError: person.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
TypeError: person.map is not a function
```

I'm getting this error while trying to print some data to the server. This is my full code:

I've been trying to search for the error but i'm not able to locate it.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDom from "react-dom";
import './index.css';

const UseStateObject = () => {
  const [ person,setPerson ] = useState(
    {age: 29, id: 1, image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1595959131/person-2_ipcjws.jpg", name:"Bertie Yates"},
    {age: 34, id: 2, image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1595959131/person-3_rxtqvi.jpg", name:"Mariano niga"},
    {age: 38, id: 3, image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883423/person-4_t9nxjt.jpg", name:"Nemesis go"},
    {age: 19, id: 4, image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg", name:"Nopam Lit"},
    {age: 78, id: 5, image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg", name:"Socra Com"},
  )
  return (
    <>
    {
      person.map((people) => {
        const { id, name, age, image } = people;
        return (
        <div key={id} class="person">
        <img src={image} />
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <p>{age}</p>
        </div>)
      })}

  </>
)
}




export default UseStateObject
```

Comment: useState([....])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to make the array brackets on the `useState`:

```
  const [ person,setPerson ] = useState([{age: 29, id: 1, image:...]);
```

Comment: Not really worth an answer. Voting to close as typo-type

Answer (score 0):

just set your state as a array!

```
  const [ person,setPerson ] = useState([
    {age: 29, id: 1, image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1595959131/person-2_ipcjws.jpg", name:"Bertie Yates"},
    {age: 34, id: 2, image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1595959131/person-3_rxtqvi.jpg", name:"Mariano niga"},
    {age: 38, id: 3, image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883423/person-4_t9nxjt.jpg", name:"Nemesis go"},
    {age: 19, id: 4, image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883417/person-3_ipa0mj.jpg", name:"Nopam Lit"},
    {age: 78, id: 5, image: "https://res.cloudinary.com/diqqf3eq2/image/upload/v1586883334/person-1_rfzshl.jpg", name:"Socra Com"},
  ])
```